# HookWebpackError:webpack.WebpackError is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, node-modules

For some reason my project was working fine and then I had made a few changes to a bunch of my React components (props, states and some of the functions within them) and when I tried running `node_modules\.bin\webpack ./app.tsx --config webpack-config.js` I got the following error: `HookWebpackError:webpack.WebpackError is not a constructor`. I have no idea what it means and couldn't find much online about it. It seems to be an issue within node_modules folder but I haven't changed the packages nor their versions so I'm unsure what's causing this issue.

**Error:**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to update Webpack from v5.0.0 to v5.74.0

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Switching from Webpack `v5.6.0` to `v5.75.0` did resolve the problem.